# Как сделать доступы по ролям когда роуты прогружаются еще до появления user в редаксе и нет возможности проверить роль?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как сделать доступы по ролям когда роуты прогружаются еще до появления user в редаксе и нет возможности проверить роль?
Получается user.role переменную с mapstatetoprops не могу проверить так как роуты первее прогружаются и я не могу определенный список определенному юзеру предоставить

```
const routes = [{
      path: '/auth/login',
      Component: lazy(() => import('pages/auth/login')),
      exact: true,
    },

<Switch location={location}>
                    <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/dashboard" />} />
                    {routes.map(({ path, Component, exact }) => (
                      <Route
                        path={path}
                        key={path}
                        exact={exact}
                        render={() => {
                          return (
                            <div className={routerAnimation}>
                              <Suspense fallback={null}>
                                <Component />
                              </Suspense>
                            </div>
                          )
                        }}
                      />
                    ))}
                    <Redirect to="/auth/404" />
                  </Switch>
```

Comment: как то не понял но роль по идее определяется после отправки лог/пасс и получения ответа? вот и надо проверку делать по этой роли и предоставить определенные роуты

Answer (score 1):

Сделать приват роут, и в нем уже проверять проверять!

```
export default ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => (
        isUserLogged() // тут проверить роль
            ? <Component {...props} />
            : <Redirect  to="" />
    )} />
)
```